# could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.MonadError

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have the following code snippet:

```
object GenderRoutes {
  def make[F[_] : Sync](query: GenderQuery[F]): GenderRoutes[F]
  = new GenderRoutes[F](query)

  implicit def genderError[F[_] : Sync]: HttpErrorHandler[F, GenderError] =
    GenderHttpErrorHandler[F]

}
```

that does not compile. The compiler complains:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.MonadError[F,io.databaker.gender.GenderError] (Could not find an instance of Monad for F)
[error]     GenderHttpErrorHandler[F]
```

The implementation of `GenderHttpErrorHandler`:

```
object GenderHttpErrorHandler {
  def apply[
    F[_] : MonadError[*[_], GenderError]
  ]: HttpErrorHandler[F, GenderError] = new RoutesHttpErrorHandler[F, GenderError] {

    override def A: MonadError[F, GenderError] = implicitly

    override def handler: GenderError => F[Response[F]] = {
      case GenderNotFound =>
        InternalServerError("Genders could not be found")
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Sync[F]` gives you a `MonadError[F, Throwable]` so it won't work for `GenderError`

Comment: It should work, because of `trait HttpErrorHandler[F[_], E <: Throwable] {
  def handle(routes: HttpRoutes[F]): HttpRoutes[F]
}`

Comment: maybe [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/RY5IRWrdTHSmz0rr48BpNQ) helps you understand what is going on. Remember [`MonadErro`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/MonadError.html) is [**invariant**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html) on the _error_.

Comment: What does this mean `A <:< B = null`?

Comment: `<:<` is a [**generalized type constraint**](https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html), it basically means A is a _subtype_ of B, or actually it demands such relationship to be true; if such relationship is not true, then the compiler won't produce a proper implicit value of such type. The `= null` part is a quick trick, if the compiler can not find an implicit value it will use `null` as a default _(of course you can use any value that type checks, as with any other default value for a parameter)_.

Comment: Could please explain, how the compiler creates the proper implicits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216786/discussion-between-zero-coding-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).